How do I make geometry nodes instances exhibit the same UV behaviour as "traditional" instances? (Blender 4.2 LTS)
I have setup a very simple blend file with two equivalent scenarios, one using "traditional" instancing, the other using geometry nodes. The geometry nodes instances have no UV data for the "Texture Coordinate" node.

There are a couple of workarounds that I know about, but both have drawbacks and exhibit different behaviour to the traditional method:

Use the "Attribute" node in the shader and specify the UV map manually.
Use the "Realize Instances" node in geometry nodes.

Is it possible to change this setup so the geometry nodes behave the same way as the traditional method?
Blend file is here:


I've just found this bug report: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/129604 so I'm wondering whether this is a simply a bug in the Blender renderer.

It's a bug
I don't know if it's properly reported yet, I thought it is, but then Blender 4.3 was released and the bug is still there, so I'll have to spend some time writing up the bug report...
Workaround
Apparently "Join Geometry" node fixes the problem, when it's not a no-op, that is it actually joins something. Immediately afterwards you can remove that temporary thing:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

I opened your linked bug report and actually it has all information needed it seems, so no need to report another one.
